# std::length_error: basic_string converting wstring to string

Tags: c++, linux

I have a task to convert a tool written in windows to run in Linux, so I have to write a function convert string to `wstring` or convert `wstring` to string in Linux.

Due to I am not familiar with c++,when I call Linux API, I have to change `string` to `char*` like function `IsFileExist` below.

If I remove function `setlocale`, error message below:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: basic_string
```

***Question***: Is this correct to use `setlocale`? Actually after google still confused about this.

---

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

/*
    string converts to wstring
*/
std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& src)     
{  
    std::wstring res = L"";
    size_t const wcs_len = mbstowcs(NULL, src.c_str(), 0);
    std::vector<wchar_t> buffer(wcs_len + 1);
    mbstowcs(&buffer[0], src.c_str(), src.size());
    res.assign(buffer.begin(), buffer.end() - 1);

    return res;
}  

/*
    wstring converts to string
*/
std::string ws2s(std::wstring const & src)
{ 
   setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");

   std::string res = "";

   size_t const mbs_len = wcstombs(NULL, src.c_str(), 0);

   std::vector<char> buffer(mbs_len + 1);

   wcstombs(&buffer[0], src.c_str(), buffer.size());

   res.assign(buffer.begin(), buffer.end() - 1);

   return res;
}

int IsFileExist(const std::wstring& name ) {
  struct stat buffer; 

  /*convert wstring to string,then to C style char* */  
  std::string str = ws2s(name.c_str());

  char *cstr = new char[str.length() + 1];

  strncpy(cstr, str.c_str(),str.size());

  /*judge if file exist*/
  if(0 == stat(cstr,&buffer))
  {
      delete [] cstr;
      return 1;
  }
  else
  {
      delete [] cstr;
      return 0;
  }      
}


int main()
{    
    std::wstring str=L"chines中文œ∑®";
    std::string res = ws2s(str);
    std::cout<<res<<std::endl;

    char dst[]="abcdef";
    std::wstring fun = s2ws(dst);
    std::wcout<<fun<<std::endl;

    std::wstring file=L"/Users/coder52/Downloads/mac.zip";

    std::cout << IsFileExist(file) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Ron I don't know how to use function setlocale,does it correct?

Comment: @Ron I read few related question in stackoverflow,It still confused me,for me I want the code run well in linux ,some of the code using "high level" c++,I just can't understand.

Comment: You've shown that you were able to copy a string into a vector in `ws2s` so why use a raw `char[]` in `IsFileExist`?

Comment: one suggestion would be to avoid the unnecessary allocation of a char array. You can just pass `str.c_str()` to the `stat` call.

Comment: It looks like `stat` takes `const char*` so there is no need to copy anything to a `char[]`. Just pass `str.c_str()`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux stat will be wrong, If not convert string to char[]

Comment: @52coder You are mistaken. `std::string::c_str()` and `std::vector<char>::data()` will give you a `const char*` and `char*` which are compatible with `stat`. A `std::vector<T>` can replace most uses of `T[]`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks I will check it later,have to goto the class.

Comment: An example of using `mbstowcs` to convert from narrow to wide with error checking can be found at [`StringWiden`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/misc.cpp#L204). It was testing using the Chinese character for "bone" from UTF-16 (0x9AA8) to UTF-8 (0xE9 0xAA 0xA8). The locale must be available. See the comments in [the header file](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/misc.h#L1355).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  thanks man,I rewrite the function to these:struct stat buffer; 

  /*convert wstring to string*/  
  std::string str = ws2s(name.c_str());

  /*judge if file exist*/
  return (0 == stat(str.c_str(),&buffer));

Comment: The C locale is global, thread-unsafe state; you cannot modify it lightheartedly in a random utility function like that. If you need to set it to something in particular, generally you have to do so at program startup, and then leave it alone forever. Or, use C++ locale facilities, as ugly as they are, at least they provide local state.

Comment: @my program just single thread,will safe? pack as a .so ,so python can call the function in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do it platform dependant. Please make it C++17 style and use [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) for the path name and check the file existance with [`std::filesystem::exists`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists). `std::filesystem::path` is able to handle both `char*` and `wchar_t*`.

Comment: thanks,I have to call many linux c api such as open stat mkdir etc,I doubt if there correspond function in C++ 17,according to @FrançoisAndrieux advice,I just use  str.c_str() to call the linux c api.

Comment: @52coder Also mkdir is part of the [filesystem support library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem). No need to doubt, just check the documentation for the great new stuff.

Comment: thans for your advice,I will check all of my code.thanks again.